# How to return an existing key on duplicate for a prepared statement (Java 8) insert (MySQL)

Tags: java, mysql

I am creating a prepared statement for MySQL and need to get the generated key if successful or the existing key if a duplicate. However, it is returning zero if a duplicate.

Java creation of prepared statement:

```
String updateQryAward = ("INSERT INTO at_cub_awards "
                + "(cd_id, att_meeting, att_date, att_description, att_new_chum, att_challenge_area) "
                + "VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?) "
                + "ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE att_meeting = ?, att_description = ?, att_new_chum = ?, att_challenge_area = ?;");
```

Execution:

```
ps4 = c.prepareStatement(insertCAQry, Statement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS);
                                        
ps4.setString(1, cdId);
ps4.setString(2, awId);
ps4.setString(3, attendance);
ps4.setString(4, unit);
                    
ps4.executeUpdate();
                    
String caId = null;
ResultSet rs = ps4.getGeneratedKeys();
if (rs.next()) {
    caId = rs.getString(1);
}
                    
// Clean up
ps4.close();
```

Comment: I'm not certain, but I think it isn't possible. In [13.2.6.2 INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html), it describes that an insert with an AUTO_INCREMENT column will return the [LAST_INSERT_ID()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/information-functions.html#function_last-insert-id) value – that's what you're seeing. When the "update" path is followed, there is no equivalent (because nothing was inserted).

Comment: INSERT [ODKU] cannot return row(s). If you want to obtain existing duplicated key expression value then you must use one more SELECT query where you use the values to be inserted in the conditions before the insertion. PS. You may use VALUES() function in ODKU part and do not provide the same values twice.

Comment: @Akina Yes it can, but only for generated keys. No key is generated when there is a duplicate, so none is returned.

Comment: @user207421 ??? Imagine that your table contains unique `(col1, col2)`. You want to insert `('val1','val2')`. You query `SELECT id FROM table WHERE (col1, col2) = ('val1','val2')`. If none returned then no interference by this unique key, and INSERT will insert new row. But if the row exists then you'll receive according PK value from the row which will be updated. Of course you must test each unique key which exists in the table.